# Does the Apple Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI adapter passthrough HDCP?

Tags: dvi, video-adapter, hdcp

I have a dual-link (2560x1440) DVI monitor connected to my computer (2015 retina MbP) through the [Apple Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB571LL/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter). It is reported as not HDCP-complient by iTunes and Netflix. Is this because the monitor doesn't support HDCP, or because the adapter doesn't pass the HDCP?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204149) says about this:

> Apple Mini DisplayPort adapters that offer digital connections—such as
>   the Apple Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI adapter and the Apple Mini
>   DisplayPort to DVI adapter—**support HDCP content**. Apple Mini
>   DisplayPort adapters that offer analog connections—such as the Apple
>   Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter—do not support HDCP content.

Also, I found this answer on an Apple site but I can't verify if it's correct so YMMV:

> Here is what I found a) Mini DP to DP will offer full resolution 2560
>   X 1080 @ 60 Hz but HDCP content from iTunes is not permitted, ie. will
>   not run; b) HDMI adapter to DVI-D allows HDCP content to run but the
>   resolution is limited to 1920 x 1080 @ 60Hz; c) HDMI to HDMI also does
>   not offer full resolution but allows access to HDCP content; finally,
>   the only configuration that offers both full resolution and HDCP is
>   with Mini Display Port to Dual DVI-D cables.